# Change color and width of Polyline - ESRI Javascript API

Tags: javascript, esri, polyline, arcgis-js-api

I have a ESRI map that has 11 polylines on it. I would like it so that when a user mouses over a line, the line changes a different color and changes to a bigger width. When a user mouses off the line, the line will go back to it's original color and width. All these lines are on the same layer (var reaches).

I have the code that detects when a user mousesover or mouseout of a line:

```
dojo.connect(reaches, "onMouseOver", function(evt) 
{ });

dojo.connect(reaches, "onMouseOut", function() 
{ });
```

They correctly detect when the mouse in over a line and when the mouse is off a line. The way I have these 2 function, they detect when the mouse is over any line in the `reaches` layer. I would like the `onMouseOver` function to know which line was moused over and change the color and the width of the line. How do I do this?

Comment: hvae u solved this issue? I am facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

> I would like the onMouseOver function to know which line was moused
>   over

The `evt` parameter given to your event handler function should have a `.graphic` property, which contains the geometry of the feature you're hovering over.

> and change the color and the width of the line

You can't do this directly on the feature without playing with its field values, but you can add a new feature to the `map.graphics` layer to serve as the highlighted feature. There's a good example on [ESRI's forums](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=158&f=2396&t=301591):

```
dojo.connect(pdaGraphicsLayer, "onMouseOver", function(evt) {
map.graphics.clear();
var highlightGraphic = new esri.Graphic(evt.graphic.geometry,highlightSymbol);
map.graphics.add(highlightGraphic);
});
```

Comment: How it can be done with out mouseover event. I mean i wanted to change all polylines width and height when a user clicks on button?